# Could I Test CAN Tranceiver with External Loopback Mode?

Tags: can

Hello I am using STM32H753 over a custom PCB. I have no any CAN Analyzer except oscilloscope, multimeter and logic analyzer. We have a problem with CAN BUS communication. I am suspecting of CAN Tranceiver but we couldn't find the root cause yet.

Normally, We designed CAN-BUS with LTC2875HDD.At time of production, this chip was not available and it is replaced by NXP TJA1462ATK/0Z which has almost identical pin-out but there is a difference how pins 5  and 8 work.

TJA1462ATK/0Z has dual voltage (VCC + VIO) pins and on pin 5 is missing IO-voltage reference 3.3V and it must be connected with an extra wire.

I tied VCC to VIO externally but CAN is still working.

I runned in external loopback mode which allow us to see the messages what we are sent on CAN TX pins.

My assumption was If I see anyhting on CAN Tx, I have to see something on CAN H and CAN L.

I have also another product which has different variant of STM32H7+ different tranceiver but its can is working.
I applied test code to this product first and I saw messages on Can Tx and also saw some signals in a suppress way that I thought because of no termination resistor at the end.
At the moment I runned same code with not-working one. I also saw messages on CAN Tx but
there is no any move on the output of CAN Tranceiver.

My question is my test was is true or still I could miss something or this test does not imply anyhting ?
[image: Current CAN Schematic]

[image: CAN TX][image: CANH]

Comment: @lundin I shared topic here, and schematic as well. R800 was empty to we tied 3v3 to new VIO pin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parts aren't compatible.

LTC2875HDD can work with either nominal supply voltage 3.3V or 5V.
TJA1462ATK/0Z uses nominal supply voltage 5V (4.5V - 5.5V). *It cannot be supplied with 3.3V!*

The Vio pin of TJA1462ATK/0Z is there to allow 3.3V logic levels but you still need to supply the part with 5V.

Pin 5: The split termination feature of LTC2875HDD cannot be used by TJA1462ATK/0Z, in case of the latter you have to use a single 120R resistor between CANH and CANL.

Pin 8: LTC2875HDD uses this for slew rate control, whereas TJA1462ATK/0Z uses this for standby mode. Best not to use this at all. If you have a requirement to use slew rate control, well then no can do with the NXP part.

Comment: I have to be sure of TJA1462ATK/0Z Supply voltage is 5V. Because we are driving at 3V3.

Comment: @EmbeddedMaker Reading the friendly datasheet makes it quite clear... They have some undervoltage detection feature, so with some luck the TJA1462 just went in latch-up and might still be undamaged.

Comment: How I missed that, I can swear that I read the datasheet :D Maybe I confused with VIO. It would not work at all. It took my two weeks :( Firstly we supposed that there is LTC2875 then we noticed we changed with TJA1462 during manufacture :D

Comment: @EmbeddedMaker LTC2875HDD seems widely available though. Unlike TJA1462ATK/0Z which is out of stock everywhere... Using 3.3V supply + DFN at the same time is a bit exotic. I know TI has plenty of 3.3V parts but only in SOIC8. Microchip have pin compatible DFN parts with split pin, but also 5V supply.

Comment: Our story and current status of chips are really vice versa :D Thank you Lundin ! I wonder that why using 3v3 supply + DFN at the same time is a bit exotic ? Are there any silicon limitation ?

Comment: @EmbeddedMaker 3V3 doesn't give ideal 2.5 +/- 1V signals as that would require some built-in boost converter. Instead 3V3 transeivers make some compromise like +/- 0.8V while still staying within the CAN spec. Also the automotive industry was very sceptical to 3V3 parts for a long time. For these reasons 5V supply is by far the most common. As for part status I see the LT part everywhere: Arrow, Mouser, Digi-Key, Farnell and so on. I can't see the NXP part anywhere, pretty much out of stock globally.

Comment: Very nice info ! Thank you thank you !!!